# Посмотреть 21 вопрос

Tags: числительные

Есть фраза "посмотреть все N вопросов". Например, для N=2 или N=5 всё очевидно:

> Посмотреть все 2 вопроса. Посмотреть все 5 вопросов.

Как будет правильно для N=21, "посмотреть все 21 вопрос"?

По мне так себе, звучит несколько неожиданно.

Comment: Как вариант: Посмотреть весь 21 вопрос.

Comment: Я бы написал так: "Посмотреть все вопросы (21)"

Answer (score 2):

Не все числовые сочетания допускаются, а говорить надо по-русски, то есть не коверкать язык. Поэтому следует как-то **изменить фразу**.

В качестве варианта: ***Посмотреть все вопросы (21 вопрос).***

Информация представлена полностью, все части предложения стилистически корректны.

Answer (score 0):

«...Звучит несколько неожиданно» — бывает. Однако формально это совершенно правильно.

Как вариант для изощрённого стилиста: «Посмотреть все вопросы — все 21».